# Table generation reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have algorithm for automatic table generation from arrays.

Array that is called array, after parsing it has look that you can see lower.

```
const array = [{dfdfd, gdgd, fgdg, dfgdg},
               {hjbhjkb, hjybjhy, jhgbjkhy},
               {fjkvdnkf, uiholuh, hjyluyg}]
```

The problem is that with my implementation the subarrays are the rows, whereas I need them to be columns.

```
  class TableGenerator extends React.Component {
render() {
    const data = this.props.data
    const words = this.props.words
    const array = []
    console.log(words)
    Object.keys(words).forEach(wordIndex => {
        const insideObj = words[wordIndex];
        const synObj = insideObj.synonyms;
        const tempArray = [];
        Object.keys(synObj).forEach(objKey => {
            tempArray.push(synObj[objKey]);
        });
        array.push(tempArray);
        console.log(array)
    })

    return (
        <Paper style={{ maxWidth: 936, marginLeft: "250px" }}>
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        {data.map((TableRow, i) => (
                            <TableCell key={i} align="center">
                                {TableRow.split("_").join(" ")}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {array.map((user, i) => (
                        <TableRow key={i}>
                            {Object.values(user).map((v, j) => (
                                <TableCell key={j} align="center">
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <AddIcon/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                    {v}
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <RemoveIcon/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                </TableCell>
                            ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>

    );
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing more information on what your intended structure has to be?

Comment: @Rallen I need array data to be names of the columns, but this parts is working as I want. The only problem appears when I work with "array" array, I generate TableBody from it and it works, but the problem is that these parts {dfdfd, gdgd, fgdg, dfgdg} of the array become the rows, but I need them to be columns